# JavaScript Camera API Android (Froyo)

Tags: android, api, html

I am trying to access the JavaScript Camera API via the Android browser as demo'd at Google IO on Froyo (yes, I have Froyo on my Nexus1).  Since there is no documentation, I am going by the W3C specs.  But, I am unable to access the navigator.device object and unable to access navigator.camera either - both return undefined.  Can anyone point me to documentation or have a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The demo at Google IO was for a future version of Android, *not* Froyo. As you saw in the demo, even the Googlers themselves couldn't get it working at first go. The demo was of a very early-stage (alpha or earlier) prototype. I don't think you can currently do what you're trying to do within the browser.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  You are correct. I just re-watched the keynote and he did indeed mention the 'next release' after Froyo.  I guess I intially figured next release was meant as Froyo.

Comment: http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/ - if you watch the bottom keynote @ 18:45 - he states that the camera, mic, etc are coming in the next release after Froyo.