# Using javascript to capture photo from iPhone / Android Camera

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, cordova

possible to use javascript (like PhoneGap, but not PhoneGap) to capture a photo? I realize that this post: http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953865/javascript-camera-api-android-froyo states that it is coming - but what about iPhone?

Comment: you can do so inside PhoneGap, but not from the stock browser at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be the proposal for client side camera/microphone access (Capture API):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/

Given that it's a draft w3c standard, it's certainly possible that iOS devices will support it, probably some time in the future.  I wouldn't assume that it will be available any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible!

Method 1: Use [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) to get video feed, and capture images from there. Not widely supported, but works in chrome and webkit webview (Android 5+). [Support tables](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc)

Method 2: Use HTML Media Capture. e.g. `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`

Here's a very comprehensive article about [media capture in mobile browsers](https://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/).

Support tables at [mobilehtml5.org](http://mobilehtml5.org/) say it's supported on Android 3.0+ and iOS 6+.